# basic function in R for multiple element vectors

Tags: r

how do I get this function to work for a vector with more than one element in it?

```
above10<-function(x){
     if(x>10) print(x)
 }
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 3):

We can get use `[` to get the numbers that are above 10 which will work for both single element and more than one element

```
above10 <- function(x) {
           print(x[x > 10])
  }

above10(11)
#[1] 11

above10(6:12)
#[1] 11 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend to use lapply

```
  x <- seq(1:20)
    lapply(x,FUN= above10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for loops

```
above10<-function(x){
for(i in seq_along(x))
  if(x[i]>10) 
  print(x[i])
}
```